# Pressure at the bottom of a swimming pool

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, pressure, water, fluid-statics

Why is atmospheric pressure it not taken into account when finding the force exerted by incompressible fluids onto a surface within the fluid? If you don't understand my question, then consider the example below:

[image]

Comment: it looks like there's air all around the swimming pool, so that atmospheric pressure acts on the other side (the dry side) of the floor of the swimming pool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find this text a bit confusing. The pressure field:
$$P(z)=P_0+\rho gz$$
assuming that $\rho$ is constant. If $z=0$ is the surface of the water, then $P_0$ is the atmospheric pressure (the pressure field is continuous).

The text you're quoting says "due to the water". The author probably sees the above formula as a sum:
$$P(z)=\underbrace{P_0}_{\text{atm}}+\underbrace{\rho gz}_{\text{water}}$$
In other words, $\rho gz$ is the *additional* pressure due to the water.

Assuming that the bottom of the pool is exposed to atmospheric pressure under it (for example because there's a tunnel letting air in from the surface), there yes, as you said, $P_0$ is present on both sides of the bottom and vanishes from the equation.

This reasoning also assumes that atmospheric pressure is constant. Since air has a very low density, this is a good approximation as long as the height difference remains reasonably small (a few dozen meters, perhaps more).

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Comment: That additional pressure (difference from atmospheric) is sometimes called gauge pressure (e.g., that seen on the gauge of your bicycle pump).  I hadn't thought about it that way, but yes it makes some sense that gauge pressure is what you'd be worried about when filling a pool.